# Lucene Search SuggestWords()

Tags: java, arrays, performance, search, lucene

I used the Apache Lucene library to do a search method.

```
   public static List<String> suggestWords(String word, Directory directory, String field) {
       blabla
   }


Text
[Text]

text
[Next, Text, Heat, Sent, Test, Texts]
```

Had any of you ever work on this library, I would like to understand why when i search for Text I am getting the good word/words and when i search for text the first suggested word is Next and not Text. Should I always put the first letter of the word to UpperCase before searching the suggestWords list ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you edit your post so it contains the Lucene code that you're actually using? What you posted seems a stub of your application, not the actual Lucene library/method being called.

Comment: LPK is right about the case sensitivity unfortunately that is not enough, I had to create another methods on my own in order to enhance the Levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 1):

In the Apache Lucene Library fields names are case sensitive. That could explain your issue with the Text and text case.

To avoid your issues, you might add a `String.toLowercase()` or Uppercase like you said, to ensure you to have the right answer.